# Differentiate exponential of a matrix times a vector

Tags: derivatives, matrix-exponential

I have:

- $\boldsymbol{r}$, a $(1 \times N)$ vector of times
- $\gamma$, a $(p \times 1)$ vector of regression parameters
- $V$, a $(N \times p)$ matrix of covariates

I want to get the expression to estimate the $\gamma$ parameters. For that I have to solve the following score equation $$\frac{\partial}{\partial\gamma}\left[V\gamma -\boldsymbol{r}\exp(V\gamma)\right]=0$$.

How to do that? I’m not sure how to differentiate the exponential of the matrix times the vector of parameters.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you even defining $\exp(V_\gamma)$? The only definition I am familiar with requires a square matrix.